# Ember.js 2.x: Handling "Could not find component..." error thrown by component helper

Tags: ember.js

I have need in my Ember.js app to render a different component based on some piece of data. I've set this up via the `component` helper, like so:

```html
<article class='awesome-article'>
    {{component article-type}}
</article>
```

This works all fine and well, though naturally, if the `article-type` attribute doesn't match the name of any component in the application (which may happen due to fat-fingering), it gives us a nice, explicit error message:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: HTMLBars error: Could not find component named "nonexistent-component" (no component or template with that name was found)
```

This is also great, but now I've got a smaller problem: I'd like to gracefully handle this error in the application, but I can't seem to figure out how to either catch or prevent this error. I've tried adding an error action to the parent component, but it skips right past it.

How can I go about handling this? This is probably one of those "missing something obvious" things, but my Google-fu has failed me this time.

Comment: There are also some route based error events you may catch this with

Comment: `Ember.onerror` indeed seems to catch it, but that seems a bit nuclear since it's going to catch way more than just this case. The `Ember.Error` object doesn't have any sort of identifiable error-type information aside from the message text, and checking it seems a bit... brittle. It's a fallback if nothing else, though.

Comment: A computed property that returns null or empty string?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a handlebars helper that looks up if the component is registered in the container and based on this information you can display it or display some placeholder component.

If you are on at least Ember 2.3 you can use the public API they added: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/RegistryProxyMixin.html#method_hasRegistration

Comment: Thanks there -- this is a big piece of the puzzle, though there's a second thing I'm stuck on that's stopping me from trying it fully (I may have to open a new question on it). More in a bit.